# How to convert a string "0bxxxx" to a binary?

Tags: python-3.x, string, types, binary

Consider the following variables as an example :

```
x = "0b1"
y = 0b1
```

I am looking for a way to convert `x` to `y`, and vice-versa.

**Edit :**
I add that I read `x` from a file, and I am not supposed to know something more than `x` can be any binary `0b1`, `0b10` ...

I would really appreciate an answer with an explanation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't have a separate type for binary numbers when you type 0b1 there it just gets interpreted as base 2 and is still stored as a base 10 integer at the end so for converting from a string '0b1' you can just convert it to int while telling it that the value is in base 2

```py
y = '0b1'
print(int(y, 2))
```

the **bin** function also just gives you a binary representation of the integer as a string

Comment: That's a beautiful answer. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this : -

```
x = "0b1"
y = 0b1

#type of x and y before change
print(type(x))
print(type(y))


x,y=y,x
print(bin(x))
print(y)

#type of x and y after change
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
```

Comment: I just edited my post, I am not supposed to know `y`. I just read `x` and it can be any binary.